# Как в php сохранять файл, который выбрал пользователь на сайте, в определенную папку в файловой системе проекта

Tags: php

Я хочу, чтобы пользователь на сайте с помощью  выбрал файл, и после он сохранился в определенную папку в проекте, чтобы с этим файлом работать в дальнейшем. Либо, если возможно, сохранить файл в phpmyadmin

Comment: сохранить файл в phpmyadmin? Что?

Comment: ну так при сохранении загруженного файла и указывайте путь. В чём сложность?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` есть в пхп для перемщения загруженных файлов. В БД сохранить тоже можно, но вряд ли стоит это делать. Обычно в БД хранят путь к сохраненному файлу.

Comment: ему на сервере надо выбрать. то есть по сути - copy(). Хотя, конечно, по вопросу видно, что человек сам не понимает, о чем спрашивает